# Bootstrap .page-header background image

Tags: css, background-image, stretch

I am playing with Bootstrap for first time, but I am a little stucked with a basic stuff like stretching of background image. My code looks like that:

CSS

```
.page-header {
    background-image: url("images/header.jpeg") ;
    -webkit-background-size: cover; /* For WebKit*/
    -moz-background-size: cover;    /* Mozilla*/
    -o-background-size: cover;      /* Opera*/
    background-size: cover;  
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

And my HTML

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ZELM</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"></span> 000 000 000</a></li>
        </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">O nás</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Katalog domů</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reference</a></li>

          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Hledat">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Hledej</button>
      </form>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Dům na klíč od společnosti ZELM <small>Postavíme vaše sny</small></h1>
</div>
    </header>
```

I was looking for solution at internet, but didnt find any answer. The problem is, that the background image is not displaying in full size, but it is stretching as the size of the screen is changing. I want to give it a strict size, which will not resize with size of window.

I dont wanna use javascript, Id like to stay in CSS and HTML for now.

Comment: Remove `background-size: cover;` from your css

Comment: Doesn´t help, but thank you :), I have removed it. No change in behaviour at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set a size for the `background-size` attribute. It could be like `background-size: 1000px 600px;` if you want to set both strict height and width, or `background-size: 1000px ;` for just width.
You could also add `background-repeat: no-repeat;` to ensure it doesnt repeat.

**CSS:**

```
.page-header {
    background-image: url("https://srilankafoundation.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Beach.jpg") ;
    -webkit-background-size: cover; /* For WebKit*/
    -moz-background-size: cover;    /* Mozilla*/
    -o-background-size: cover;      /* Opera*/
    background-size: 1000px ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ZELM</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"></span> 000 000 000</a></li>
        </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">O nás</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Katalog domů</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reference</a></li>

          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Hledat">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Hledej</button>
      </form>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Dům na klíč od společnosti ZELM <small>Postavíme vaše sny</small></h1>
</div>
    </header>
```

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b1sc2zjj/) of your code.
For more info, look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp).

Comment: Thanks man, it changed my thinking about the problem. The problem is that I have to change size of the .page-header with size of the screen. Then, when I have this css:

.page-header {
 background-image: url("images/header.jpeg") ;
 -webkit-background-size: contain; /* For WebKit*/
    -moz-background-size: contain;    /* Mozilla*/
    -o-background-size: contain;      /* Opera*/
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;}

I can just change size of window via media queries.  Thanks man u took me the lighting.

Comment: great! please edit my answer and add the correct final solution, might help somebody later...

Comment: Okay, no idea how :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fixed image size specify the exact values (width height) like so: `background-size: 600px 600px`. Or you can do this `background-size: 600px;` where the height value defaults to `auto`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: ok by this isnt very responsive solution. Do I have to place various of images into media queries to have the full size image at background at every screen?